# Laravel 5.2 - Delete duplicates from my query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a query like this:

```
$players = PostBalance::where('post_id', $post->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

It work well and return array with all values, **Post balances** have fields:

```
ID
score
post_id
user_id
```

I would like Delete user_id duplicated AND get the max score value. for example if i have:

```
[0] = 'id' => 1 , 'score'=> 10, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1
[1] = 'id' => 2 , 'score'=> 20, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1
[2] = 'id' => 3 , 'score'=> 30, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1
[3] = 'id' => 4 , 'score'=> 40, 'user_id'=> 2, 'post_id' => 1
[4] = 'id' => 5 , 'score'=> 50, 'user_id'=> 2, 'post_id' => 1
[5] = 'id' => 6 , 'score'=> 60, 'user_id'=> 2, 'post_id' => 1
```

I would like delete duplicates user_id and get only the user_id with max score:

**RESULT:**

```
[0] = 'id' => 3 , 'score'=> 30, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1
[1] = 'id' => 6 , 'score'=> 60, 'user_id'=> 2, 'post_id' => 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupBy()` and `max()` method like this (note: this will not actually delete the duplicates from DB, but work for your query):

```
$result = PostBalance::groupBy('user_id')
                    ->max('score');
```

For further reference, see [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Or if you want to order the results by `score`, you can do it like this:

```
$result = PostBalance::orderBy('score', 'desc')
                     ->groupBy('user_id')
                     ->get();
```

**Note:** To get max of group by, try to first run `orderBy()`, then run `groupBy()` on the query instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it return only max score value = 30, not array [0] = 'id' => 3 , 'score'=> 30, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1

Comment: According to me max would be single result if you're trying to pick out the max from a set of results, isn't it?

Comment: i would like array result with not duplicated user_id and max score for each user. like the example result in description question. Im tryng to insert orderBy but it doesn't work well

Comment: See my updated answer, hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: i tryed like this yes but it return: [0] = 'id' => 3 , 'score'=> 10, 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1
[1] = 'id' => 6 , 'score'=> 40, 'user_id'=> 2, 'post_id' => 1 return the minimum values score. :/